# After Undeploying or delete say at 4th page it should remian on the same page but it comes back to first page

Tags: bootstrap-table

Bootstrap table pagination, delete any list say for eg; at 4th page it should remain at 4th page, but it comes to 1 page.

1. Create a bootstrap table.
2. Make 3,4 pages.
3. select any list from any page and delete it , after delete it should remain on the same page after refresh the current page.

[image: e]

Comment: Can you provide some code, I think I know what you're trying to ask but I'm not completely sure, maybe re think your explanation and add a bit more detail

Comment: <button id="undeploywfdId" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please select the workflow to undeploy the workflow." class="btn btn-default btn-md">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove text-info"></span> Undeploy Workflow
            </button>

Comment: var pageNumber = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getOptions').pageNumber
alert(pageNumber)
  $('#table').bootstrapTable('selectPage', pageNumber);